# Find div inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, if-statement

I want to check if child3 exists in parent2 or not.
If child3 exists it will show alert "exists" otherwise "element doesnt exists".
But it seems if/else statement is not working. I use alert before if/else to test if the function is working or not.
Following is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div class="parent1">
<div class="child1">Child1</div>
<div class="child2">Child2</div>
<div class="child3">Child3</div>
</div>

<div class="parent2">
<div class="child1">Child1</div>
<div class="child1">Child2</div>
</div>

<button onclick="find()">search</button>



<script>
function find()
    {
alert('testing function working');

if($collection.children().is(".child3")){ alert('exists');}

else{alert('Element doesnt exists');}
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're probably looking to do `if ($collection.children(".child3").length)...`. Note how the `children` method accepts a selector argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do :

```
if($('.parent2 .child3').length > 0)
   alert("exists");
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/1h89hs65/